# angular2: How to use observables to debounce window:resize

Tags: angular, observable

so i am trying to figure out a way to debouce window:resize events using observables, so some kind of function would be called only after user stoped resizing window or some time has passed without size change (say 1sec).

https://plnkr.co/edit/cGA97v08rpc7lAgitCOd

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div (window:resize)="doSmth($event)">
      <h2>Resize window to get number: {{size}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  size: number;
  constructor() {
  }

  doSmth(e: Event) {
    this.size = e.target.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

is just a simple sample that uses window:resize and shows that it reacts instantly (use "Launch preview in separate window").

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think that you can't debounce this way using observable. In fact, such things aren't supported out of the box right now but there is an open issue for this:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062

To achieve your goal, you could use directly the `Observable.fromEvent` to get an observable for this event. So you can apply the `debounceTime` operator on this observable.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class App {
  size: number;
  constructor() {
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .debounceTime(1500)
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.doSmth(event);
        });
  }

  doSmth(e: Event) {
    console.log('do smth');
    this.size = e.target.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/uVrRXtnZj8warQ3qUTdN?p=preview

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps this article could interest you: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 ;-)

Comment: It seems like this is now the current bug/issue for this feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248

Comment: Modern version:    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.alive = true;
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.alive),
        debounceTime(500)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.gridApi?.sizeColumnsToFit();
      });
  }

Answer (score 12):

In one of our apps we also had the implementation Thierry Templier proposes, but I noticed that Angular's change detection is firing (a lot) on window resize, which makes our app slow on resize.

Fixed it by using zones & Subject, like so:

```
private changeSubject = new Subject<number>();

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
    .debounceTime(1500).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe((e: Event) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.changeSubject.next(e);
      })
    }
    )
  });
  this.changeSubject.subscribe((e: Event) => { this.doSmth(e); });
}
```

See plunker with the issue [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/k9VykjvObUTAiY7xjSPn/) (resize screen and watch console).

And plunker with the fix for this issue [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/UyV9P8Fu48nYbOKGJh9b/) (resize screen and watch console).

Answer (score 11):

You can use [@HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator. This is a common way to subscribe events like this.

```
@Component({
   // ...
})
export class App {
  private changeSize = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.changeSize
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(
      throttleTime(1000)
    )
    .subscribe(innerWidth => console.log('innerWidth:', innerWidth));
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event.target'])
  public onResize(target) {
    this.changeSize.next(target.innerWidth);
  }
}
```

You can read more about `@HostListener` [here](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener/) or [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/listening_to_an_element_host.html).

Comment: After rxjs 6  you have to use .pipe(throttleTime(1000))

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
   // ...
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  resize$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resize$.debounceTime(300).subscribe(
      innerWidth => console.log('innerWidth:', innerWidth)
    );
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event.target'])
  onResize(target) {
    this.resize$.next(target.innerWidth);
  }
}
```