# Angular2 watching parent's css attribute

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular

I have a directive which adds the number of pixels corresponding to its parent `right` css attribute

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from "angular2/core"

 @Directive({
     selector: "[d]"
 })
 export class PositioningFromParent implements AfterViewInit {
     private el:HTMLElement

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      let v = this.el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().right
      this.el.style[left] = v + "px"
    }
 }
```

It works just fine. However, if I do resize my window, my parent is changing and its `right` value as well. My directive doesn't adapt that value at the minute. How could I watch the `this.el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().right` value in Angular2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to resize and update when the event is fired:

```
 @Directive({
     selector: "[d]"
 })
 export class PositioningFromParent implements AfterViewInit {
     private el:HTMLElement

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.updateLeft();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize') 
    updateLeft() {
      let v = this.el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().right
      this.el.style[left] = v + "px"
    }
 }
```

See also [angular2: How to use observables to debounce window:resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199434/angular2-how-to-use-observables-to-debounce-windowresize) to limit the rate the code is executed during resize.